# HTML append a class based on the name of current class JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to append a class to the current class name?

```
<li class="myWrap"></li>
```

Then `onClick` toggle class:

`$('.myWrap').toggleClass('selected');`

Is there anyway I can read the current class i've select and appended it to my one i'm adding. So my new class instead of:

`<section class="myWrap selected"></section>`

It will be:

`<section class="myWrap myWrap_selected"></section>`

Comment: Use `$(this).attr('class', 'myWrap_' + $(this).attr('class'));`

Comment: If having multiple classes, use replace, `$(this).attr('class', $(this).attr('class').replace('selected', 'myWrap_selected'));`

Answer (score 1):

[`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) can already do this for you but you will need a way to determine the base class, because at any given point your elements can have more than one class (the base class, the selected class and any others). If you ensure that your base class will remain the first specified, then you can use the following.

```
$('li').on('click', function() {

    // find the base class
    var baseClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];

    // toggle the selected class
    $(this).toggleClass(baseClass + '_selected');
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('li').on('click', function() {
    var baseClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    $(this).toggleClass(baseClass + '_selected');
  });
});
```

```css
li.myClass {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  background-color: #ffcccc;
}
li.myClass_selected {
  border-style:solid;
}
li.myWrap {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
}
li.myWrap_selected {
  border-style:solid;
}
li.otherClass {
  font-style:italic;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="myClass otherClass">Hello class</li>
  <li class="myWrap otherClass">Hello wrap</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, but I need it dynamic. I have a lot of `li` tags. onClick I need to take the current class, add a new class name like, `currentClass_selected`. Then toggle that on and off `onClick`

Comment: @MeMyselfAndI, I noticed you updated your requirements, for which my old solution was unsuitable. Please see updated code.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myWrap').on('click', function() {
      var newclass = $(this).attr('class') + "_selected";
    $(this).toggleClass(newclass);
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: $(this) returns an object, not the current class that the element has. So, this will definitely not do what you expect.

Comment: I have modified answer. Please check it now.

Comment: Again modified my answer.

Comment: Why are you canceling the event? Why did you include a `DOMContentLoaded` handler? Explain your code and/or remove irrelevant portions.

Comment: @ MeMyselfAndI, Now it fulfill your new requirement